# org.json.JSONException w/ Google Places

Tags: android, google-places-api, org.json

I've searched and searched for an applicable answer, but everything I find does not fit.

I used the tutorial at (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-displaying-places-of-interest--mobile-16145) to identify local venues (restaurants, etc) from my current location. However, unlike the tutorial, my local places don't show up.

My manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant" >

<permission
    android:name="com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MAPS_API_KEY"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".contact"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".map"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".gallery"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".link"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".split"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

The activity containing the Map is as follows:

```
package com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;


public class map extends Activity {
private GoogleMap map;
private LocationManager locMan;
private Marker userMarker;
private int userIcon, foodIcon, drinkIcon, shopIcon, otherIcon;
private Marker[] placeMarkers;
private final int MAX_PLACES = 10;
private MarkerOptions[] places;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    userIcon = R.drawable.yellow_point;
    foodIcon = R.drawable.red_point;
    drinkIcon = R.drawable.blue_point;
    shopIcon = R.drawable.green_point;
    otherIcon = R.drawable.purple_point;

    if(map==null) {
        //map not instantiated yet
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }

    if(map != null){
        //ok - proceed
    }
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    placeMarkers = new Marker[MAX_PLACES];
    updatePlaces();
}
private void updatePlaces(){
    locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
    double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();

    //update location

    LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    if(userMarker!=null){userMarker.remove();}
    userMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(lastLatLng)
            .title("You are here")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
            .snippet("Your last recorded location"));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng), 3000, null);

    String types = "food|bar|store|museum|art_gallery";
    try {
        types = URLEncoder.encode(types, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?" +
            "parameters" +
            "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
            "&radius=500&sensor=true" +
            "&types=" + types +
            "AIzaSyASEbnPuqb-_Y8N_CqBfqSw9ZPVLWQt0lQ";

    new GetPlaces().execute(placesSearchStr);
}

private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    //fetch and parse place data

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... placesURL) {
        //fetch places

        StringBuilder placesBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        //process search parameter string(s)
        for (String placeSearchURL : placesURL) {
            //execute search

            HttpClient placesClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                //try to fetch the data
                HttpGet placesGet = new HttpGet(placeSearchURL);
                HttpResponse placesResponse = placesClient.execute(placesGet);
                StatusLine placeSearchStatus = placesResponse.getStatusLine();

                if (placeSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    //we have an OK response
                    HttpEntity placesEntity = placesResponse.getEntity();
                    InputStream placesContent = placesEntity.getContent();
                    InputStreamReader placesInput = new InputStreamReader(placesContent);
                    BufferedReader placesReader = new BufferedReader(placesInput);
                    String lineIn;
                    while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        placesBuilder.append(lineIn);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return placesBuilder.toString();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //parse place data returned from Google Places
        if(placeMarkers!=null){
            for(int pm=0; pm<placeMarkers.length; pm++){
                if(placeMarkers[pm]!=null)
                    placeMarkers[pm].remove();
                try {
                    //parse JSON
                    JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray placesArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");
                    places = new MarkerOptions[placesArray.length()];
                    //loop through places
                    for (int p=0; p<placesArray.length(); p++) {
                        //parse each place
                        boolean missingValue=false;
                        LatLng placeLL=null;
                        String placeName="";
                        String vicinity="";
                        int currIcon = otherIcon;
                        try{
                            //attempt to retrieve place data values
                            missingValue=false;
                            JSONObject placeObject = placesArray.getJSONObject(p);
                            JSONObject loc = placeObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
                            placeLL = new LatLng(
                                    Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lat")),
                                    Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lng")));
                            JSONArray types = placeObject.getJSONArray("types");
                            for(int t=0; t<types.length(); t++) {
                                //what type is it

                                String thisType = types.get(t).toString();
                                if (thisType.contains("food")) {
                                    currIcon = foodIcon;
                                    break;
                                } else if (thisType.contains("bar")) {
                                    currIcon = drinkIcon;
                                    break;
                                } else if (thisType.contains("store")) {
                                    currIcon = shopIcon;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            vicinity = placeObject.getString("vicinity");
                            placeName = placeObject.getString("name");

                        }
                        catch(JSONException jse){
                            missingValue=true;
                            jse.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if(missingValue)    places[p]=null;
                        else
                            places[p]=new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(placeLL)
                                    .title(placeName)
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(currIcon))
                                    .snippet(vicinity);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(places!=null && placeMarkers!=null){
                    for(int p=0; p<places.length && p<placeMarkers.length; p++){
                        //will be null if a value was missing
                        if(places[p]!=null)
                            placeMarkers[p]=map.addMarker(places[p]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splash, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My logcat errors look like this over and over again:

```
08-27 18:07:02.577  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 18:07:02.577  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-27 18:07:02.577  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-27 18:07:02.577  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-27 18:07:02.577  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 18:07:02.577  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant.map$GetPlaces.onPostExecute(map.java:176)
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant.map$GetPlaces.onPostExecute(map.java:130)
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-27 18:07:02.587  26474-26474/com.WreckinApp.MaJoRProduct.wbiassistant W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
```

What I do recognize are map.java:130

```
private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

and map.java:176

```
JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

but I don't know what is wrong with each line seeing as I went step by step in the tutorial. They'd shown up once before in a test app, but I've since (stupidly) deleted it and I just need the local places to show up and they are not. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What does the URL look like when you make the request?  If you put that in a browser and view the results does the JSON look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's nothing wrong with your code. Please check your URL.

```
String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?" +
        "parameters" +
        "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
        "&radius=500&sensor=true" +
        "&types=" + types +
        "AIzaSyASEbnPuqb-_Y8N_CqBfqSw9ZPVLWQt0lQ";
```

Your URL includes the word "output?" it means either json or xml output and the "parameters" must be ommitted. It should look like this:

```
String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?" +
        "location="+lat+","+lng+
        "&radius=500&sensor=true" +
        "&types=" + types +"&key=AIzaSyASEbnPuqb-_Y8N_CqBfqSw9ZPVLWQt0lQ";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Seems to have done the trick. I thank you! This has been plaguing me for a couple weeks now. On to the next part! Woo Hoo!!

Answer (score 0):

At your while loop, When reading the response, you read it while more line exists.
but you're inserting without line breaks.

I'm not sure if it'll help, but maybe it damages the Json encoding.

```
           while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    placesBuilder.append(lineIn + "\n");
                }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no change, but I do appreciate your help.